# NameError: name 'rabinerJuangStepPattern' is not defined when using dtw

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis, nameerror, dtw

I'm trying to run this code from [Kaggle](http://%20https://www.kaggle.com/timib1203/time-series-clustering-for-forecasting-preparation). For clustering time series using DTW.
More specifically the part:
In[24/25]:

```
"""
From a list of series, compute a distance matrix by computing the 
DTW distance of all pairwise combinations of series.
"""
diff_matrix = {}
cross = itertools.product(cols, cols)
for (col1, col2) in cross:
    series1 = daily_sales_item_lookup_scaled_weekly[col1]
    series2 = daily_sales_item_lookup_scaled_weekly[col2]
    diff = dtw(
        series1, 
        series2,
        keep_internals=True, 
        step_pattern=rabinerJuangStepPattern(2, "c")
        )\
        .normalizedDistance
    diff_matrix[(col1, col2)] = [diff]
return diff_matrix
```

As one of the parameters, the authors claim "step_pattern=rabinerJuangStepPattern(2, "c"))" however, when I run it, I get the error mentioned.
Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't copy code that you don't really understand. Here `rabinerJuangStepPattern` seems to be a function, but you didn't create it or import it.

Comment: most likely because this is being run as a notebook, you forgot to run a snippet before it, that defined this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import this function from the dtw package like this first:

```
from dtw import *
```

If you scroll to the top of the Kaggle Page you can see that it is imported there too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I've already imported and the error persists.

Comment: Ok, did you also install the dtw-python package? Please make sure you installed the "dtw-python" and not the "dtw" package.

Comment: I had both installed. Now I uninstalled both and installed dtw-python again but I still get the error.

Comment: Ok that's strange. If you are using this in a notebook, did you run the block of code importing the package before running the block of code using the function?

Comment: Yes. I when run "?dtw" I get: " dtw(x, y, dist, warp=1, w=inf, s=1.0) Computes Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) of two sequences." doesn't look like there is a parameter such as step_pattern...

Comment: This means that you imported the wrong package. The dtw function you describe is from the dtw package, not from the dtw-python package. See https://github.com/pierre-rouanet/dtw/blob/6c080af4ca0ff12c0eba1fd4eb678260bb0b4f9f/dtw/dtw.py#L6